# Node simple form issues using enctype multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, forms, multer

In my Node app i have a simple form like this:

```
<form action="/createProject" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="project-field">
    <p class="subtitleFont project-field-name">NOME</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="project-field">
    <p class="subtitleFont project-field-name">IMMAGINI</p>
    <input type="file" multiple name="images" required>
  </div>
  <div class="project-field">
    <button type="submit">Crea progetto</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the app.js configuration:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const routes = require('./server/routes/index.js');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(routes);

app.set('layout', './layouts/main');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(port, () => {console.log('Listening to port '+port+'!')});
```

The multer configuration is this:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, 'public/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

When i trigger the action and console.log serverside req.body and req.files they seem to be empty.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you have no bodyparser installed or didn't enable multipart formdata support for it? Please show the relevant code/configuration.

Comment: I added more info in the description.

Comment: I don't see anything capable of parsing multipart formdata in your middlewares, only `x-www-form-urlencoded` (`express.urlencoded(...)`). I can however see you put `multer` as tag - where is that used?

Comment: multer is used in routes.js to upload files on server and the configuration is above.

Comment: It sounds like you don't invoke Multer for the `/createProject` route then...

Comment: Can you please say me how to do that in the route?

Comment: See the first examples [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage). You have to add for example `upload.array('images')` as middleware in your route.